# Filter values without subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am trying to get the values for only the latest survey date, if the user filled the survey more than once.

However since the response table is huge, i would rather not do this in a subquery in the where clause

```
select *
from responses r1
where r1.survey_date = (select MAX(survey_date) from responses r2 where
r1.user_id = r2.user_id);
```

Here's an example with loaded data
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/chUhe2HjoAa9QRNmp5pfSv/3

Comment: Since you are only considering dates (without  hour) for your max, what if a user have two surveys in the same day? What should be the one to be chosen?

Comment: Your column "survey_date" have one index?

Comment: Ahmad, not completely sure, but think that what you wrote here might actually be the best solution, performance-wise, especially if you add index to your survey_date field.

Comment: How big is "huge"?

Comment: @JorgeCampos, there are other columns in my DB, i just left them out for simplicity

Comment: @GordonLinoff few hundren millions

Answer (score 1):

This query should be fine:

```
select *
from responses r1
where r1.survey_date = (select MAX(survey_date) from responses r2 where
r1.user_id = r2.user_id);
```

You simply need an index on `responses(user_id, survey_date)`.

Comment: This is not an option for me as the performance is too low, then i can just do the filtering in code rather than SQL